# Recovering from tty

Tags: xubuntu, tty

Using XUbuntu 13.10.

Some key combination -- maybe CTRL-ALT-ESC or something similar -- keeps throwing me into a full-screen tty. When that happens, how do I get back to Xubuntu? I can log in to the tty with my username and pw, but I don't know how to return to my graphical session.

Comment: In your case, you probably need to press `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to a full screen TTY, you generally do CTRL-ALT-F1

The F1 part can F2, F3, F4, F5 or F6 Allowing 6 TTYs

To get back to the desktop it should be CTRL-ALT-F7

Comment: Sorry if this isn't completely correct, as I am on Ubuntu 14.04
CTRL-ALT-ESC does nothing for me

Comment: Yes, CTRL-ALT-F7 fixes it; CTRL-ALT-F1 was what puts me into tty in the first place. Thanks!